# Reference Angular binding from javascript

Tags: angularjs

I'm looking for a (best-practice) way to iterate through a list of elements in the scope of an angular controller and generate a div with an element specific id and append a svg to the element specific div. I'm very new to Angular...and suspect that the following attempt fails because I misunderstand Angular bindings?

What is a better way to do the following:

```
<div id="top_level">
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
  <div id={{item.id}}>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var svg_img = build_svg(args);
      document.getElementById({{item.id}}).appendChild(svg_img);
    </script>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What does your function build_svg return?

We'd need a little more information about the kind of end-result you would like to get.

But yeah, it's not really good practice to have a script element within a ng-repeat directive.

I see two solutions here:

1- Build your SVG directly within the ng-repeat

```
    <div id="top_level">
    <div ng-repeat="item in items">
      <div id={{item.id}}>
        <svg height="{{item.svg.attrs.height}}" width="{{item.svg.attrs.width}}">
           <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke- width="3" fill="red" />      
          </svg>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Here is a plunker of this method: 
http://plnkr.co/edit/g58BUPScjKHjRLAfx6ks?p=preview

2- Create a directive to generate your SVG with some additional parameters and flexibility.

```
    <div id="top_level">
    <div ng-repeat="item in items">
      <div id={{item.id}}>
        <my-svg attrs="item.svg.attrs"></my-svg>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

The my-svg directive would generate a SVG element with the attrs parameters.

Comment: Thank you @Jeremy I'll probably need to create directives for this eventually. Currently pursuing  Davids proposal.

Answer (score 1):

You should place your logic inside of your controller and conditionally render as much html as necessary rather than invoking a script tag inside of an ng-repeat..

```
<div ng-controller="YourCtrl">
  <div id="top_level">
    <div ng-repeat="item in items">
      <div id={{item.id}}></div>
      <div ng-bind-html="$scope.buildSvg(item)">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In your angular controller, you would then add a function to build out and return the svg for you to render.

```
app.controller('YourCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.buildSvg = function (item) {
        // add logic here.
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for this proposal. I've been tinkering with it, but struck some problems with $sce in Angular. I tried expressing the problem as a new question to include more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30854229/rendering-svg-via-angular-ng-bind-html